# Let $K$ be an algebraic number field. Prove that $O_K$ contains infinitely many prime ideals.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, dedekind-domain

Let $K$ be an algebraic number field. Prove that $O_K$ (collection of integral elements) contains infinitely many prime ideals.

Now this is Dedekind domain. Now what should be the next step?

Comment: What can you say about the simplest number field $\mathbf Q$?

Comment: $\Bbb Q(a)$ where $a$ is integral. Still not getting it!!

Comment: Please help me!!!

Comment: Alex was alluding to the ground field of rationals - why does the statement hold in this case? How could you go from there to any finite extension?

Comment: Can you please answer me in details